# Exception in java code when calling hadoop file system

Tags: java, hadoop

hello every one i am working on hadoop and in that i configure 2 node hadoop cluster . I have to create directory in hadoop file system using java code but every time when i run this code i get some exception.

My java code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class Hadoopjava {

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException

    {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        /*conf.addResource(new Path("core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("hdfs-site.xml"));*/
            conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://master:54310");


        String dirName = "dd";

        //values of hosthdfs:port can be found in the core-site.xml  in the fs.default.name

        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path path = new Path("/user/hduser/dd/gg");
        fileSystem.mkdirs(path) ; 

       // System.out.println(data);
        /*Path path = new Path("/user/hduser/dd");
        if (fileSystem.exists(path)) {
            System.out.println("Dir " + dirName + " already exists");
            return;
        }

        // Create directories
        fileSystem.mkdirs(path);*/

        fileSystem.close();
    }
}
```

Exception in my code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Call to master/192.168.0.128:54310 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:95)
    at com.widevision.hadoop.Hadoopjava.main(Hadoopjava.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:446)
```

i am using eclipse IDE for java code.

what is wrong in my code ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are compiling your code against the same Hadoop version that you are running on your cluster. Looks like a protocol mismatch between different protocol versions.

Comment: thank you so much sir for answering my question sir i am running same version on all system which is in cluster.

Comment: Which version of Hadoop are you using?Is this code sitting on a remote machine?

Comment: sir i am using hadoop 1.2.0 sir and this code is on same machine sir .

Comment: Let me think a bit in that case. This normally happens due to version mismatch. And please show me your NN log file as well.

Comment: NN log sir i am not aware about that sir ?

Comment: NameNode log file. It should be inside your hadoop-1.2.0/logs folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38178/discussion-between-simmant-and-tariq)